# Azure backup warning in post script error code 1

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, azure-backup-vault

I use the app-consistent backups in Azure for VMs running Linux where you have the VMSnapshotScriptPluginConfig.json file that specified pre-script and post-script parameters for your backup. So, everyday the backup finish succesfully but sudenly last night the finish with warning. When the program was going to executed the post scripts it fails, but the backup finished succesfully but with a warning and I would like to know why it fails.

This is the message of Azure

[image]

So, I looked in the logs and it returned this:

[image]

I was looking over the Internet what is the meaning of that error, but I didn't find anything

Answer (score 1):

This error is returned by post script itself. It is just passed through and recorded in the logs. Hence it is best to contact the author of post script.

Just for your information, Azure backup is now providing managed pre-post scripts (instead of just a framework to author pre-post scripts) as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/backup/backup-azure-linux-database-consistent-enhanced-pre-post).